# definition of group variety action

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Sorry for my bad English.

In Hartshorne pp.272~273, he defined action of group variety as follows.

> A group variety $G$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ is a variety $G$, together  with morphisms $\mu:G \times G\to G$ and $\rho:G\to G$, such that the set $G(k)$ of $k$-rational points of $G$ (which is just the set of all closed points of $G$, since $k$ is algebraically closed) becomes a group under the operation induced by $\mu$, with $\rho$ giving the inverses.
> We say that a group variety G acts on a variety $X$ if we have a morphism $\theta:G\times X\to X$ which induces a homomorphism $G(k)\to \operatorname{Aut} X$ of groups.

I think when we are given $\theta: G\times X\to X$, we have group homomorphism $G(k)\to \operatorname{Aut} X(k)$. But Hartshorne says there is $ G(k)\to \operatorname{Aut} X$.

What is definition of $G(k)\to \operatorname{Aut} X$? Help me, thanks.

Comment: It's been a while since I touched this material, but doesn't an automorphism of $X$ itself necessarily take $k$-points to $k$-points? In that case we get an embedding $\operatorname{Aut} X(k) \to \operatorname{Aut} X$, and composing your map with the embedding we get Hartshorne's map.

Comment: What is definition of embedding Aut $X(k)\to $Aut $X$？